# Boost spirit split rules into different headers

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I want to parse the following structure (for the sake of simplicity I will show only the half of it but the rest of the structure is the same as the one presented):

```
*Point, name=1, mission=mission2, inherit_point=bla
*Sn
    22,-22.5
    22,22.5
    22,22.5
    22,22.5
    22,22.5
    22,22.5

*Material
    22.55,22.55,22.55
    22.55,22.55,22.55
*Kt
 1

*Output
    sequiv_fat, sequiv_propa

*End Point
```

Each section (starting with *) will be parsed into a structure. The main section Point will contain the sub-sections Sn,Material and Output. It will also have the attributes name, mission and inherit_point.

- Sn section will be parsed into a 

  `struct Sn {
    std::string name // "Sn"
    std::map<int,double> data;
  }`
- material into

  `struct material {
     std::string name // "material"
     std::vector<double> data;
  }`
- Kt

  `struct Kt {
    std::string name; // "kt"
    int value;
  }`
- Output

  `struct Output {
    std::string name; //"output"
    std::vector<std::string> data;
   }`

To parse this section, I've taken the an example from Boost Spirit which I've modified.

Having a large section to be parsed,I was thinking to split the grammar rules into separated classes. My thoughts were to have a rule for each sub section to be parsed and a main rule to parse the Point section. 

Each `sub rule` will be parse into its corresponding structure.

To do this, I need to be able to pass the lexer to each "sub rule" but I don't know to do that.

Here is what I've done sofar.

As you can see from the grammar definition, the rule Assigment_Rule2 is defined in a separated file but I don't know how to pass the the lexer to this rule. Moreover it doesn't compile.

```
    #define BOOST_VARIANT_USE_RELAXED_GET_BY_DEFAULT
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_real.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_eol.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#include "example.hpp"


using namespace boost::spirit;
using boost::phoenix::val;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  class definition
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

namespace client {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    struct point
    {
        std::string name;
        std::string name2;
        std::string mission;
        std::string parent_point;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::point,
    (std::string, name),
    (std::string, name2),
    (std::string, mission),
    (std::string, parent_point)
)

namespace client {
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Token id definitions
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    enum token_ids
    {
        ID_CONSTANT = 1000,
        ID_START_POINT,
        ID_END_POINT,
        ID_SN,
        ID_MATERIAL,
        ID_IDENTIFIER,
        ID_INTEGER,
        ID_FLOAT
    };

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Token definitions
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    template <typename Lexer>
    struct example6_tokens : lex::lexer<Lexer>
    {
        example6_tokens()
        {
            // define the tokens to match
            identifier = "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*";
            constant = "[0-9]+";
            float_value = "-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?";

            this->self = lex::token_def<>('(') | ')' | '=' | ',' | '*';

            this->self.add
            (constant, ID_CONSTANT)
                ("Point", ID_START_POINT)
                ("End Point", ID_END_POINT)
                ("Sn", ID_SN)
                ("Material", ID_MATERIAL)
                (identifier, ID_IDENTIFIER)
                (float_value, ID_FLOAT)
                ;

            this->self("WS")
                = lex::token_def<>("[ \\t\\n]+")
                | "\\/\\*[^*]*\\*+([^/*][^*]*\\*+)*\\/"
                ;
        }

        lex::token_def<std::string> identifier;
        lex::token_def<unsigned int> constant;
        lex::token_def<double> float_value;
    };
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Grammar definition
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

namespace client {

    template <typename Iterator, typename Lexer>
    struct example6_grammar
        : qi::grammar<Iterator, point(), qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> >
    {
        template <typename TokenDef>
        example6_grammar(TokenDef const& tok)
            : example6_grammar::base_type(start)
        {
            using boost::spirit::_val;
            using boost::spirit::qi::eol;
            using qi::on_error;
            using qi::fail;
            using qi::debug;


            start
                =   '*' 
                    >> token(ID_START_POINT)
                    >> ','
                    >> assignment2
                    >> ','
                    >> assignment2
                    >> ','
                    >> assignment2
                    >> *statement 
                    >> '*' 
                    >> token(ID_END_POINT)
                ;

            statement
                = sn_stmt
                | material_stmt
                ;

            assignment
                = tok.identifier >> '=' >> expression
            ;

            sn_stmt = ('*' >> token(ID_SN) >> +pair)
                [
                    std::cout << val("sn statement to: ")
                    << _1 << "\n"
                ]
            ;

            material_stmt = ('*' >> token(ID_MATERIAL) >> +list)
                [
                    std::cout << val("material statement to: ")
                    << _1 << "\n"
                ]
            ;

            list = token(ID_FLOAT) % ',';

            pair
                = token(ID_CONSTANT) >> ',' >> token(ID_FLOAT)
                ;

            expression
                = tok.identifier[_val = _1]
                | tok.constant[_val = _1]
                ;

            sn_stmt.name("sn_stmt");
            material_stmt.name("material_stmt");
            debug(sn_stmt);
            debug(material_stmt);
        }

        typedef boost::variant<unsigned int, std::string> expression_type;

        qi::rule<Iterator, point(), qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> > start;
        qi::rule<Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> > statement, material_stmt, pair, list, assignment;
        qi::rule<Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer>> sn_stmt;

        qi::rule<Iterator, expression_type(), qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> >  expression;
        Assigment_Rule2<Iterator> assignment2;
    };
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    typedef std::string::iterator base_iterator_type;

    typedef lex::lexertl::token<
        base_iterator_type, boost::mpl::vector<unsigned int, std::string, double>
    > token_type;

    typedef lex::lexertl::lexer<token_type> lexer_type;
    typedef client::example6_tokens<lexer_type> example6_tokens;
    typedef example6_tokens::iterator_type iterator_type;

    typedef client::example6_grammar<iterator_type, example6_tokens::lexer_def> example6_grammar;

    example6_tokens tokens;                         // Our lexer
    example6_grammar calc(tokens);                  // Our parser

    std::string str(read_from_file("ReadMe.txt"));

    std::string::iterator it = str.begin();
    iterator_type iter = tokens.begin(it, str.end());
    iterator_type end = tokens.end();

    std::string ws("WS");
    client::point my_point;

    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, calc, qi::in_state(ws)[tokens.self], my_point);

    if (r && iter == end)
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Bye... :-) \n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

File BasicRules.hpp

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_real.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_eol.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_char_.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_lexeme.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit;
using boost::phoenix::val;

namespace client {
    template <typename Iterator>
    struct Assigment_Rule2
        : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::string()>
    {
        Assigment_Rule2()
            : Assigment_Rule2::base_type(start)
        {
            using boost::spirit::double_;
            using boost::spirit::lexeme;
            using boost::spirit::ascii::char_;

            start = ( "2">> '=' >> "2" )
                [
                    _val = _2
                ]
            ;
        }

        qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> start;
    };
}
```

I would appreciate if anybody can give me some ideas and some starting points.
Thanks.

Comment: Please simplify the code to be self-contained, minimal. Right now, we don't know nothing about your lexer, little about your grammar, and nothing about the namespaces involved. Also, you describe nothing relevant to the separation of the translation units (cpp files)

Comment: To be honest, maybe you should share the grammar and example inputs you want to parse, and we'd be able to help write a (simpler) parser for it.

Comment: That edit is excellent. I will give this some attention, probably over the weekend